# PdfSharp Image Filter is empty string

Tags: image, decode, pdfsharp

I have a pdf I'm trying to decode.
For the first several pages of the document the image type is "/FlateDecode".
Suddenly the image type becomes am empty string ("") for the rest of the document.
The rest of the fields appear to be Ok. (Height,Width, etc).
Does this mean I should use the previous valid decode type?

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible with corrupted files.

For a non-corrupt file, I would assume that empty filter means no filter. FlateDecoder has a CRC, so trying FlateDecode to see if it is packed is a possible approach. You can still assume an unfiltered block if you get a CRC error.

Comment: I tried continuing with the previous valid type and it seems to work.